# Stylus only input-mode on Android

Tags: android, tablet

How can I turn on the "pen-only" mode programatically on the Lenovo Thinkpad Tablet running ICS 4.0.3?

Answer (score 2):

I'm very sorry that I can't answer your question, though I think WebnetMobile might be right - there doesn't seem to be an API method for pen-only mode. However if you go to this article http://knowledge.lapasa.net/?p=490 it states that you should focus on the diameter of the input device (the touch diameter of a finger is much greater than that of a pen stylus).

As for WebnetMobile saying it is pointless to use a tablet in pen-only mode, I'd say that it is a longed for feature of any artist or note taker to be able to rest your hand on the surface upon which you're drawing/writing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing an app, you can actually implement this. If your stylus can "hover" on your screen before it touches, you can add an `OnHoverListener` on the highest View in your activity to set a global variable `isPen` to true. Then override `dispatchTouchEvent()` in your activity and check the variable before passing on the event in your app.

```
rootView.setOnHoverListener(new View.OnHoverListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onHover(View view,MotionEvent event) {
        isPen = true;
        return true;
    }
});
```

And

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if(isPen) {
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I found nothing else on this problem and I eventually come out with this solution: you need to extend your view and override onTouchEvent:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // Disable multitouch
    if (event.getPointerCount() != 1)
        return false;

    // If not stylus return  
    MotionEvent.PointerProperties pp = new MotionEvent.PointerProperties();
    event.getPointerProperties(0, pp);
    if (pp.toolType != MotionEvent.TOOL_TYPE_STYLUS)
        return false;

    // Dispatch event to the original view 
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```